# Apache Ignite : Unable to establish secure connection. Was remote cluster configured with SSL?

Tags: server, ignite

I referred to the Ignite docs on TLS and configured keyStoreFilePath & trustStoreFilePath

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/ssltls.

However when I start my nodes, they don't discover one another.

> class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Unable to establish secure
>   connection. Was remote cluster configured with SSL?
>   [rmtAddr=myremotehost/ipaddr,
>   errMsg="sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted
>   certificate found"]

Comment: What is your trust store?
Does it contains full certificate chain to your cert can be verified?

Answer (score 0):

You should generate server.jks file first, then configure file path and password in XML for each node.

Commond line:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias server -keyalg RSA -keystore server.jks
```